# how to add"shell tools" target in Xcode?there's no such choice after i clicked the add target

Tags: xcode, shell, xcode5, target

I searched for instructions .it seems that the old version xcode actually have the "shell tools" choice after clicked "add target", how mine is xcode 5.0.2.how to add "shell tools" target then? Thanks!